# Passing value to thread start method in c#, when thread is created in loop

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am creating threads in loop and I need to pass the counter of loop (as it was when the thread was created) in thread start method.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ListSize; i++)
{
    thread = new Thread(() => 
        Helper.GetEndToEndRequestProcessTime(EmailList[i], reqResultData, i, ListSize));
    workerThreads.Add(thread);
    thread.Start();
}
```

In above example `i` is the variable I as argument in `GetEndToEndRequestProcessTime()`. But the issue is when actually thread is starting value of `i` is changing and I am getting wrong result in `GetEndToEndRequestProcessTime()`.

How can I make sure that at the time when thread starts the value passed to `GetEndToEndRequestProcessTime()` is same as supplied when thread was created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem here is, as mentioned, a *closure* problem.

What this means is that because you only allocate a single variable for `i`, when you capture it by referencing it in `new Thread(() => ...)` you're actually copying the address of the variable. Thus, when the variable is incremented for the next loop, the action underway in the first `thread` will get the updated value, because it all points back to the single value of `i`.

The way to fix this is is to copy the variable into a new one, and then capture the new variable. By having it declared in the loop, a new one will be made for each iteration, since the loop's inner scope is not shared between iterations.

Note a similar problem applies to the capture variable in a `foreach` loop for .NET 4.0 and earlier, but was fixed in 4.5 and above.

Comment: Absolutely worked, thanks a lot. I am c and c++ developer new bee to c#, so only the memory allocation is killing some time :)

Comment: Now if I had known that, I'd have used the word "pointer" far more liberally. But yet, it's a memory allocation and pointer/value passing issue ;3

Answer (score 5):

A classical *closure and captured variables* problem every newcomer must ask.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ListSize; i++)
{
    var j = i;
    thread = new Thread(() => Helper.GetEndToEndRequestProcessTime(EmailList[j], reqResultData, j, ListSize));
    workerThreads.Add(thread);
    thread.Start();
}
```

For more Info: http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter5/closures.aspx

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make sure that at the time when thread starts the value
>   passed to GetEndToEndRequestProcessTime() is same as supplied when
>   thread was created?

**Answer:** By creating a local copy which will remember what the value of `i` was when the order to execute was given to this task/thread and then passing this local copy.

**Exact Issue:** By the time you start your task/thread, the value of `i` has changed and therefore your execution is unexpected.